# Templated class with templated static member function no match for prototype in implementation

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

In the making of a library I encountered the following problem :

Let's have four files :

- main.cpp
- nsp/nsp.hpp
- nsp/A.h
- nsp/A.cpp

Below is the content of each file

#### main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "nsp/nsp.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main(){
  vector<int> v = {0, 1};
  nsp::A<int> a = nsp::A<int>::from(v.begin(), v.end());
  cout << a.getElem();
  return 0;
}
```

#### nsp/nsp.hpp

```
#ifndef NSP_HPP
#define NSP_HPP

namespace nsp{};

#include "A.h"

#endif
```

#### nsp/A.h

```
#ifndef NSP_A_H
#define NSP_A_H
namespace nsp{
    template <class T>
    class A{
        protected:
            T elem;

            A();

        public:
            A(T e);

            template <class It>
            static A<T> from(It begin, It end);

            T getElem();
    };
};
#endif
```

#### nsp/A.cpp

```
#include "A.h"

template <class T>
nsp::A<T>::A(){}

template <class T>
nsp::A<T>::A(T elem){ this->elem = elem; }

template <class T, class It>
nsp::A<T> nsp::A<T>::from(It begin, It end){
    nsp::A<T> tmp;

    if(begin != end)
        tmp.elem = static_cast<T>(*begin);

    return tmp;
};

template <class T>
T nsp::A<T>::getElem(){ return this->elem; }
```

Despite the fact that this code seems correct to me (no syntax errors) and that the IDE (CLion) I am using indicates that all member functions have been implemented, I am given the following error at compile time :
`(nsp/A.cpp) error: prototype for 'nsp::A<T> nsp::A<T>::from(It, It)' does not match any in class 'nsp::A<T>'`

followed by
`(nsp/A.h) error: candidate is: template<class T> template<class It> static nsp::A<T> nsp::A<T>::from(It, It)`

I would like to know what is the cause of this error and how I may solve it.

Comment: Do `template<class T> template<class It>` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When defining a template member from a template class, you have to write `template <...>` twice:

```
template <class T>
template <class It>
nsp::A<T> nsp::A<T>::from(It begin, It end){
    nsp::A<T> tmp;

    if(begin != end)
        tmp.elem = static_cast<T>(*begin);

    return tmp;
}
```

But you have another problem: [**template functions can only be defined in header files**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file) (unless you wish to enumerate all types your templates should work for in advance, the link should explain that too).

You can either define your member functions inside the class body, or below the class in the header file; whatever you like more.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, separating the template types and putting the implementation in the header file solved the issue.